# Finding the degree of a differential equation

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, nonlinear-system

I am trying to find the degree of the following differential equation:
$$
\sqrt{\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}}+\frac{dy}{dx}=y^3.
$$

I am not $100$% sure, but I know (correct me if I'm wrong) that for a differential equation to have a degree, it has to be able to be represented as a linear polynomial like the following :

$a_{0}(x)y+a_{1}(x)y'+a_{2}(x)y''+...+a_{n}(x)y^{(n)}+b(x)=0$

Therefore, I did the following reasoning :

$\sqrt{\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}}+\frac{dy}{dx}=y^3\Rightarrow \sqrt{\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}}=y^3-\frac{dy}{dx}\Rightarrow \frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=(y^3-\frac{dy}{dx})^2\Rightarrow \frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=y^6-2y^3\frac{dy}{dx}+(\frac{dy}{dx})^2\Rightarrow -y^6+(2y^3-\frac{dy}{dx})\frac{dy}{dx}+\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=0$

After representing the differential equation in a linear polynomial form, I concluded that the degree of the differential equation is $1$. But for some reason, the term: $(2y^3-\frac{dy}{dx})\frac{dy}{dx}$, puts me off and I don't know if this is considered to be a linear term. If any of you people could help me out, that would be very kind of you.

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Sorry about that, I do not know how to use MathJax, but I will try to update it as such.

Comment: No problem.  The tutorial will really help get you going.  Questions that don't use MathJax tend to attract downvotes so keep this in mind for future posts.  Good luck!

Comment: I think you're overcomplicating this: the order of an ODE should simply be the order of the highest-order derivative in the equation. So in the original equation, as in your expansion, the order is just $2$ as there is a second derivative.

Comment: The term $(2y^3-y')y'=(2y^3)y'+(y')^2$, so your ODE is $y''+(2y^3)y'+(y')^2=y^6$, which, as per the definitions I looked at, doesn't have a defined degree because it is not polynomial in the derivatives (it cannot be put in the form $\sum_i a_i(x,y(x))(y^{(i)})^{m_i}=f(x,y(x))$; for there is both a $y'$ and a $y'^2$ term in the ODE). I should mention that the definitions of "degree of an ODE" I found are conflicting. Some allow the $a_i$'s to be functions of $x,y(x)$, others only allow it to be a function of $x$ and not $y(x)$. Some even omit it/use it interchangeably to refer to order of ODE.

Comment: If the definition suggests that more terms of $y^{(k)}$ with different multiplicity can simultaneously occur in the ODE and coefficients can be functions of both $x,y(x)$, then your ODE has a defined degree of 1 (the exponent of $y''$). Otherwise, the degree is undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Differential equations have both a degree and an order. The order of a differential equation is order of its highest-order derivative. The degree is the power to which the highest order derivative is raised after re-expressing the equation with integral powers. So after the squaring you performed, the highest derivative has order 2 and its power is 1. So the order is 2 and the degree is 1.

[Diff Eq Terms](https://www.efunda.com/math/ode/generalterms.cfm/)

Comment: Thank you very much !

Comment: It should be noted that not all ODEs have a defined degree. For example, $\sin(y')=x$ does not have a degree (though it has an order of 1). Like OP said, I'm still unsure if the degree is 2, because from the definitions I looked, I think the ODE doesn't have a defined degree, but I could be mistaken.

Comment: Also, I should add: the definitions of "degree of an ODE" are conflicting between different texts and many textbooks even omit the notion of degree of an ODE and mention only the notion of order, which is more useful for the study of ODEs.